# UI Freeze on dispatch_async (adding new row to uitableview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to load new rows to the end of a `UITableView` when the user scrolls to the end. When the user does so, I want to call an XML URL web service and fetch new data from hayoola.

Everything works well and the new rows are added now, but the UI freezes up at the end of the `UITableView` every few seconds, and then unfreezes.

Here's the code I'm using to fetch and add the new rows:

```
if ((unsigned long)indexPath.row == [self.entries count] - 1){
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
                    ^{
                        NewsFetchParseOperation *p = [[NewsFetchParseOperation alloc]init];
                        NewsFetchAppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


                        p.cat = appRecord.Category;
                        self.intindex = self.intindex + 1;
                        p.index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)self.intindex];
                        p.lastid = appRecord.ids;
                        [p main];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                                       {

                                           NSArray *temp =[self.entries arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:p.appRecordList];
                                            self.entries = temp;
                                           [self.tableView reloadData];

                                       });
                    });

 }
```

Comment: yes but still laggy when i hit end of the list.
my guess is [self.tablevoew reloaddata] is making this kinda lag

Comment: are you doing any heavy loading operations in your table view datasource delegate methods? If so try to improve those.

Comment: What's happening in `[self.tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to try to determine whether `[self.tableView reloadData]` does actually take a long time. You can do so the "right" way, using Instruments, or the "easy" way, by commenting it out and seeing if the lag disappears (although the `UITableView` won't reload its data, obviously).

Comment: @user3807551 are you able to solve the issue?

Comment: no , still trying to find out a way. there is major lag and im trying to find out how to work with instrument.